# Angular Build is getting failed

Tags: angular

I have issue related to Angular build. Below is my dependencies in package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.15.3",
"@ngtools/webpack": "^6.2.9",
"alertifyjs": "^1.11.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"d3": "^5.9.2",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
"ngx-toastr": "^9.1.2",
"nyc": "^14.1.1",
"popper.js": "^1.15.0",
"rxjs": "^6.2.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"},


"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
"@angular/cli": "~6.2.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
"@types/d3": "^5.7.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "^3.5.3"}
```

and i am trying to run application with npm start which is returning me error like,

Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION

```
Error: Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
    at _error (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:8:11)
    at getApiMember (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:11:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:50:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:28:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ketan.jariwala\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-02T10_58_01_702Z-debug.logCould not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
Error: Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
    at _error (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:8:11)
    at getApiMember (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:11:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:50:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:28:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ketan.jariwala\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-02T10_58_01_702Z-debug.logCould not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
Error: Could not find API compiler-cli, function VERSION
    at _error (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:8:11)
    at getApiMember (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:11:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngtools_api.js:50:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Ketan\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:28:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help please! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to use compiler-cli ver 8.2 wth Angular 6. "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.0". Please use version 6 of "@angular/compiler-cli"

Comment: @Ketan any update ?

Comment: Yeah, i finally tried tilde(~) option with angular compiler cli instead of caret(^) sign like i removed this "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.3 and added this @angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.0" in package.json file. and now it is working well. Thanks @TonyNgo

Answer (score 0):

Try below given command:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli
```

It will install above given packages.

Then you need to do `npm start` or `ng serve`

Comment: Tried this approach, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

first you have to remove node_module . Then clear npm cache.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

```
npm cache clean --verify --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm i @angular/core
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some version difference between your cli and compiler-cli versions.
Uninstall every module globally. Clear your cache and then re-install all the modules.

```
$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli
```

Also check if tslib has to be added to your package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    ["tslib": "^1.9.0"]
}
```

and repeat the above steps. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these command to see if it work.

```
npm uninstall angular-cli -g
npm uninstall angular-cli --save
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli --save
npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save
```